# Installing Apache Solr: Permission Denied

Tags: solr, installation

I am using iMac to run Apache Solr in command line. done the following:
wget https://apache.mirrors.nublue.co.uk/lucene/solr/8.5.1/solr-8.5.1-src.tgz
tar -xzf solr-8.5.1-src.tgz

`cd to /solr`

i then typed : `bin/solr start` and got `permissions denied`.

I tried `sudo bin/solr start -force`
and got `:password: type password`
after typing the password i get `sudo: bin/solr command not found`

I read that I need to change the solr home directory for better installation as it is denying root access probably?

Comment: You want to download the binary release if you're just going to run Solr - https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/lucene/solr/8.5.1/solr-8.5.1.tgz . There should be no need to be root to start Solr, after extracing the archive `cd solr` and `bin/solr start -c` should work fine as a regular user (important: no `/`)

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to [download the binaries](https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/lucene/solr/8.5.1/solr-8.5.1.tgz) instead of the source files, then run:

```
cd solr/bin
solr create -c yourCore
solr start -p 8983
```

Answer (score 0):

You should download and install the version without scr at the end:
https://apache.mirrors.nublue.co.uk/lucene/solr/8.5.1/solr-8.5.1.tgz

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The issue was identified with JAVA version installed on my MAC.
E.g., When I wanted to install and run SOLR 5.6 - I need JAVA 8 to be installed on my system. Once, this condition is met - the issue is gone.

Answer (score -1):

Change the permission to to bin folder
something like:
sudo chmod -R 777 bin

Comment: do not suggest chmod 777 (https://pimylifeup.com/chmod-777/)

Comment: ok 774 would be enough then.